# Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise edition virtual machines licenses

Tags: virtualization, windows-server-2008-r2, licensing

It is known that with Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise edition you get to run 4 virtual machines with Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard edition.
Problem is that we don't know where to get the license key for them. Should we use the same license key as we used for our host machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the same license key for the Standard Edition VMs.

Comment: +1 - On the Technet portal, Enterprise and Standard both generate the same keys. I'm guessing it generates enterprise keys, which can also be used on Standard.

Comment: Note: If you rebuild your VMs on a regular basis, MS will only let you automatically activate them so many times (I don't remember the exact number). After that, you'll have to call and explain to the nice CSR that you're just rebuilding an image and they'll give you the million digit number to enter.

Comment: Ok, thanks Chris. Good old Microsoft activation process :)...